# Gnuplot resources

Tags: graphics, graph, gnuplot

I'll be working with some graphics so I'll use gnuplot for this, I've only used this for simple works, but now i would like to get some more beautiful graphics I've some examples what I can do with gnuplot. However I don't have how to start I need some examples of scripts  with beautiful outs,I need some pages, papers or what else that help me.  Here are some graphics that I would like to do[No exactly the same, but the settings colors yes]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo614.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lKtJ.png

Comment: which answer was the most usefull to you? I have a similar question and if you could mark/upvote the better answer based on your experience that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples on the official sites, for example [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/) and [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/screenshots/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent and comprehensive Gnuplot documentation by T. Kawano of the Los Alamos National Lab here: [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716113648/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html)

It provides examples of gnuplot usage ordered by common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one "[GNUPlotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/)" to be particularly good.